# MySQL - Compare TWO tables and SUM them

Tags: mysql, join, select, sum

I'm struggling on how to compare to **TWO** tables against eachother whilst totaling (SUM) them up.

For example i have the follow 2 tables:

**TABLE 1**

```
tablename: master
col1: code
col2: categories
```

DATA

```
 categories     code
 GP              a01
 GP              a02
 GP              a03
 DENTAL          d01
 DENTAL          d02
 DENTAL          d02
 DENTAL          d03
 DENTAL          d04
 OPTOM           o01
```

**TABLE 2**

```
tablename: submissions
col1: code
```

DATA

```
  code
  a01
  a02
  a03
  d04
  d01
  o01
  a03
```

I need to link both tables by **code** to see who has submitted in the submissions table and who hasnt then work out the overal percentage:

**My ideal result:**

```
categories   codes_total    received    outstanding   percentage received
category 1       200           40            160             20%
category 2       100           10            90              10%
```

I've thave no idea where to start really other than this??:

```
 SELECT categories, sum(total1), sum(total2), sum(total3) FROM (

  (SELECT categories, count(*) t1
  FROM master) as total1,

  (SELECT categories, count(*) t2
  FROM master
  LEFT JOIN submissions ON submissions.code=master.code) 
  )as total2,

  (SELECT categories, count(*) t3
  FROM master
  LEFT JOIN submissions ON submissions.code=master.code
  WHERE submissions.code IS NULL) 
  )as total3

) FOO
  GROUP BY categories
```

I am going in the right direction???

Comment: Hi Max.  Can you give us data sample?

Comment: HI DanB i've updated my question with some DATA included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select master.categories, count(*) codes_total,
        (select count(*)
                    FROM master master2
                            inner join submissions on master2.code = submissions.code
                    where master2.categories = master.categories) received,
        count(*) - (select count(*)
                    FROM master master2
                            inner join submissions on master2.code = submissions.code
                    where master2.categories = master.categories) `outstanding`,

        (select count(*)
                    FROM master master2
                            inner join submissions on master2.code = submissions.code
                    where master2.categories = master.categories) / count(*) * 100 as `percentage received`

from master

group by master.categories
order by master.categories;
```

Comment: Thank you!...so close! but its saying GP has none received.

Comment: You want to exclude categories with 0 received code, right?

Comment: I want to include everything ideally, So all categories are displayed by showing the total of master categories, received, oustanding and percentage - this is for a dashboard

Comment: Does my last update doesn't show right value, with all categories, including those with 0 submission?

Comment: You beauty!...thats done the trick!!!!....Thank you for taking the time out to help me with this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190017/discussion-between-max-thorley-and-danb).